# How can i create And configure SSL between IHS and WAS

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, ibmhttpserver

I have installed the IHS from archive file then configured it and it worked
So when run this command its unable to open ikeyman

```
<Ihs_home_bin>ikeyman.bat
```

It does not work it gives me:

```
Error:Could not find or load main class com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.Ikeyman
```

So how can I handle this error or how can i download this package

Comment: The archive install doesn't include java. If you want to run ikeyman, you need to provide your own IBM java.  The included certificate management is IHS_HOME/bin/gskcapicmd

Answer (score 0):

The archive install doesn't include java. If you want to run ikeyman, you need to provide your own IBM java. The included certificate management is IHS_HOME/bin/gskcapicmd

However with traditional WAS no certificate management on the webserver is necessary.  WebSphere manages a keystore for the WAS Plug-in that trusts the right certificate authorities in use by the cell:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTJ_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.ihs.doc/ihs/tihs_install_config_twas.html